# Get Filtered or Searched result of GridControl

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol, itemsource

**i used devexpress component**

i set data for **ItemSource** property of **GridControl** in code behhind like this :

```
grid.ItemsSource = query ;
```

query is List

when i filtered or searched in gridcontrol , display rows changed
now i want to get the changed itemsource like this :

```
DataSource = ((IEnumerable)grid.ItemsSource).ToList();
```

How Can I do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of modifying DataSource directly, first bind it to a BindingList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and perform filtering on the binding list.

Also, refer to solution to the DataSource updating problem here: [Updating of BindingSource in WinForms does not update Datasource Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571451/updating-of-bindingsource-in-winforms-does-not-update-datasource-collection)

Comment: i test it but when filtered the grid , itemsource not changed

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this problem by

```
GridControl.DataController.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows()
```