# How to convert treeView to Json?

Tags: c#

As the title above how to convert treeView to Json? I check a few links online such as [Convert a Treeview to JSON using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275335/convert-a-treeview-to-json-using-c-sharp), but I still don't understand how to convert TreeView to JSON.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET or WCF or something else? Firstly, you have to know: json is for data exchange among platforms or applications. C#.NET provides different methods to convert between C# data format and Json data format. For most of them, you don't need to know how the magic works. the only thing you need to discover is the API for your project or platform or case. To details your requirement will help.

Comment: To Start with, how are you generating the TreeView ? Did you explore on JSON Serialization in C#?

Comment: I answered this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275335/convert-a-treeview-to-json-using-c-sharp/54845249#54845249